# Is this intertwiner a scalar, working over a field which is not algebraically closed?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $(V,\rho_V)$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $G$ over $F$.

Define $P:V\rightarrow V$ by $P=\frac{1}{|G|}\cdot\sum_{g\in G}\text{trace}(\rho_V(g^{-1}))\cdot\rho_V(g)$.

Then $P$ is a homomorphism of representations.

If $F$ is algebraically closed, then $P$ is the scalar $1$.

In general, $P$ is an isomorphism of representations $V\rightarrow V$. Does it have to be a scalar?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar{V} = V \otimes_F \bar{F}$ be the base change to an algebraic closure. Let's write $\bar{V} = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \dots \oplus W_n$ as its decomposition into irreducibles. These are non-isomorphic but form a single Galois orbit of irreducible representations.

Then $P=\frac{1}{|G|}\cdot\sum_{g\in G}\text{trace}(\rho_V(g^{-1}))\cdot\rho_V(g) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{g\in G}\text{trace}(\rho_{W_i}(g^{-1}))\cdot\rho_{W_i}(g)$

The operators $\sum_{g\in G}\text{trace}(\rho_{W_i}(g^{-1}))\cdot\rho_{W_i}(g)$ act by $1$ on $W_i$ and $0$ on all other irreducible representations, hence $P$ acts by $1$ on $\bar{V}$ and therefore on $V$.

Comment: This approach looks good to me, but I think some information is lacking. For example, in the second equality there's a actually a triple summation, but most summands cancel out and we're left with the double summation, right? Also, in the last sentence it should be "hence $P$ acts by $1$ on..", if I'm not mistaken.                 Am I correct about these issues?

Comment: No, the second equality is just a double sum, I'm just using that trace is additive on a direct sum decomposition. Yes, the last sentence should read "hence P acts by 1..." I will correct that.

Comment: In that second equality, you replace the trace by a sum of traces, but you also replace $\rho_V$ by $\rho_{W_i}$. What is the justification for the second replacement? That's what I thought of justifying with another summation, and cancellation.